# Showing $\int_0^1\frac{\log(t^4-t^2+1 )}{t-1} \,dt=\frac{11\pi^2}{72}-\frac{\log^2(2+\sqrt3)}2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

We have:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{\left(t^4-t^2+1 \right)}}{t-1} \,dt=\frac{11}{72}\pi^{2}-\frac{\log^{2} \left(2+\sqrt{3} \right)}{2}\tag{1}.$$
Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha are unable to deal with it
(see [Wolfram Alpha response](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+log%28x%5E4-x%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28x-1%29+dx+from+x%3D0+to+1)).
The proof I have follows from the dilogarithm function. As suggested by @J.G here it is:
\begin{equation}\mathrm{Li}_2(z)=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(1-zy)}}{y}dy,\tag{2}
\end{equation}
and Euler's formula:
\begin{equation}\mathrm{Li}_2(z)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log{(1-z)}\log{(z)}.\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Li}_2(z)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-z)=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{((1-tz)(t(z-1)+1))}}{t} dt \\=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log{(1-z)}\log{(z)},\tag{4}
\end{align*}
Then if $z_{1}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2}i$  and  $z_{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, we deduce from $(2)$:
\begin{align*}i)\hspace{.5cm}\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{Li}_2(z_{1})+\mathrm{Li}_2(z_{2})\right)=\mathrm{Re}\left(-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(1-z_{1}t)}}{t}dt-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(1-z_{2}t)}}{t}dt\right)=\\
-\frac{1}{2}\left( \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(t^2(2+\sqrt{3})-t+1)}}{t}dt+ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(t^2(2-\sqrt{3})-t+1)}}{t}dt\right)=
-\frac{1}{2}(I_{1}+I_{2}).
\end{align*}
In other hand with $(4)$ we obtain:
\begin{align*}I_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{((1-tz_{1})(t(z_{1}-1)+1))}}{t} dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(t^2(2+\sqrt{3})-t+1)}}{t}dt =-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\log{(1-z_{1})}\log{(z_{1})}\\=\frac{\pi^2}{144}+\frac{\log^2{(2+\sqrt{3})}}{4},\end{align*} and
\begin{align*}I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{((1-tz_{2})(t(z_{2}-1)+1))}}{t} dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(t^2(2-\sqrt{3})-t+1)}}{t}dt=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\log{(1-z_{2})}\log{(z_{2})}\\=-\frac{23\pi^2}{144}+\frac{\log^2{(2-\sqrt{3})}}{4}=-\frac{23\pi^2}{144}+\frac{\log^2{(2+\sqrt{3})}}{4}.\end{align*}
Then replacing $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ in $i)$ we have:
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{Li}_2(z_{1})+\mathrm{Li}_2(z_{2})\right)=\frac{11}{144}\pi^{2}-\frac{\log^{2}(2+\sqrt{3})}{4}.\tag{5}$$
Then observe that:
$$I_{1}+I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(-(y^2(\sqrt{3}+2)-y+1)(y^2(\sqrt{3}-2)+y-1))}}{y}dy,$$
since $-(y^2(\sqrt{3}+2)-y+1)(y^2(\sqrt{3}-2)+y-1)=y^4-4y^3+5y^2-2y+1$, then:
$$I_{1}+I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(y^4-4y^3+5y^2-2y+1)}}{y}dy\overset{y=1-t}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log{(t^4-t^2+1)}}{t-1}dt,$$
and the result follows from $(i)$ and $(5)$.

**Question:**
Can we prove this integral using known series expansions or in an alternative way?

A proof without using the dilogarithm "function" is so appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say "function"? The dilogarithm function *is* a function

Comment: In words of Don Zagier: "If the dilogarithm can be considered as a function" @FShrike

Comment: That's frankly silly, and evocative of the old fashioned view of a function as something which you can easily write down with a (basic) formula

Comment: I'm with you but we are not Don. :) @FShrike

Comment: Could you show us the proof that uses the dilogarithm? We wouldn't want to make suggestions that turn out to lead there. For example, I suspect there's a solution using a dogbone contour, but for all I know you've got that already.

Comment: Sure, I will improve the question with the solution, thanks @J.G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2+x^4)}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\ln(1-x^2+x^4)\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)dx$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{36}+\frac{\ln^2(2+\sqrt 3)}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\boxed{\frac{\ln^2(2+\sqrt 3)}{2}-\frac{11\pi^2}{72}}$$

---

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(1-x^2+x^4)}{1-x^2}dx\overset{1-x^2\to x}=\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x+x^2)}{x}dx$$
$$=\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{x}dx}_{x^3\to x}-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=-\frac13\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{36}$$

---

$$\mathcal K=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2+x^4)}{1-x^2}dx$$

$$\small \overset{\large x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+14x^2+x^4)}{x}dx}_{x^2\to x}-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac14\mathcal J(\operatorname{arccosh} 7)-\mathcal J(0)$$

$$\small \mathcal J(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+2x\cosh t +x^2)}{x}dx \Rightarrow \mathcal J '(t)=2\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh t}{(x+\cosh t)^2-\sinh^2 t}dx=t$$

$$\Rightarrow \mathcal K= \frac14\int_0^{\operatorname{arccosh} 7} t\, dt
-\frac34\mathcal J(0)= \frac{\ln^2(2+\sqrt 3)}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Comment: Thanks @Zacky , nice proof.

Comment: $\arccos(7)$ is imaginary, how to compute it without introducing any complex numbers in the intermediate steps?

Comment: @MathFail why do you want to avoid introducing any complex numbers?

Comment: What I wanted to elude is dilogarithm function and Zacky has done it @MathFail

Comment: Seems a missed dx in I(t) @Zacky

Comment: If it is to use real method, then it is completely real. If it is a complex method, then it is completely complex. If it is a mixture, then we have to justify it, so I try to avoid the mixture. @Zacky

Comment: @MathFail alright alright, I've made some changes.

Comment: great, thank you! @Zacky